# Fail2ban log filled with Warning for DNS

Tags: fail2ban

I have just updated my jail.local file. Then I restarted fail2ban in the log file is filling up with Warning about DNS Lookup of the localhost. I removed some jail from the jail.local file and I think that the problem is the MySQL jail. The problem persists even if I stop the MySQL service.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

2021-01-27 22:06:48,288 fail2ban.filter         [13594]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: localhost = ['127.0.0.1']

2021-01-27 22:06:48,288 fail2ban.filter         [13594]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: localhost = ['127.0.0.1']

2021-01-27 22:06:48,289 fail2ban.filter         [13594]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: localhost = ['127.0.0.1']

2021-01-27 22:06:48,290 fail2ban.filter         [13594]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: localhost = ['127.0.0.1']

2021-01-27 22:06:48,290 fail2ban.filter         [13594]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: localhost = ['127.0.0.1']

2021-01-27 22:06:48,291 fail2ban.filter         [13594]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: localhost = ['127.0.0.1']

Comment: Is your localhost (127.0.0.1) on the IP whitelist?

Comment: I have this configuration in jail.conf 

ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8. But the point is that I have this problem with mysql-auth jail. But in the MySQL log I don't see all these connection attempt. There is a WARNING each millisecond.

Comment: So put a pattern in the jail filter that ignores localhost.

Comment: Ok, but I can't understand why this problem is occurring now and not before. I have similar servers with the same configuration and without this problem. If fail2ban check every millisecond this rule maybe there is a service that produces these logs? I would like to understand the problem before stop it with a workaround.